# Why is the extra space coming at the end while trying to convert an upper case letters to lowercase and vice versa in java

Tags: java, string

I wrote a code in java to convert upper case characters into lowercase and vice versa.I checked each edge cases for example for an empty string,invalid string or a string containing spaces.

Ques:Why is the extra space comes when i use the following input String `s=new String(" ")`

OutputShown

3232

String s=new String("ab cd");

OutputShown

97 98 32 99 10032AB CD

Below is my Code

```
class Change
{
    static void change(String p)
    {
        if (p == null) 
        {
            System.out.print("Null String");
        }
        int f = p.length();
        if (f == 0) 
        {
            System.out.print(" Empty String");
        }
        else 
        {    
            int u = 0;
            int i = 0;
            byte d = 32;
            char c[] = p.toCharArray();
            byte b[] = p.getBytes();
            for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) 
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(b[i]);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
               {
                if (b[i] >= 65 && b[i] <= 90) 
                {
                    b[i] = (byte) (b[i] + d);
                }
                else 
                 {
                    if (b[i] >= 97 && b[i] <= 122)
                    {
                        b[i] = (byte) (b[i] - d);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        if (b[i] == ' ') 
                        {
                            System.out.print(b[i]);
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            System.out.print("Not a valid character");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            String s2 = new String(b);
            System.out.print(s2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        String s2 = new String("ab cd");
        change(s2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting the text to *bytes* at all? That's a horrible idea, and error-prone, particularly the way you're doing it. Also, it would be easier to read your code if you could indent it properly. Now, have you debugged through your code to see what's going on?

Comment: There is much easier solution for this task. You can split the string according to spaces, then iterate on the resulted array and turn each `charAt(0)` to lowercase.

Comment: Why don't you just use String's toLowerCase() and toUpperCase() methods?

Comment: @JonSkeet Skeet How is the idea horrible.Internal implementation of toLowerCase or toUpperCase can be same what i wrote.I can't analyze any more examples where the code can be horrible considering only array and strings concept.May u please give an example?No i haven't debugged the code as a debugger line by line Sorry  but will do it while posting future answers.

Comment: @JalajChawla: No, the internal implementation won't be using `byte` at all. Nor will it rely on the platform-default encoding, as yours does. "Lower case" and "upper case" are textual concerns - not binary concerns. Use `char`, `String` etc for text handling, and `byte` for binary handling.

Comment: @JonSkeet but then ch[i]=(char)(ch[i]+32) doesn't work.Also individual character leaves us with no option.

Comment: @JalajChawla: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? And I don't know what you mean by "leaves us with no option".

Comment: @JonSkeet Sir i mean't how one character and a byte gets added.It is producing correct output but character Ascii position is added  i have not used its ascii position.I have only used its index position.

Comment: @JalajChawla: You're adding an `int` to a `char` - using its UTF-16 code value, basically. That's a lot more well-defined than adding an `int` to a `byte` which is potentially only *part* of an encoded character, which happens to be in the default platform encoding.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sir Okay i understand that u say use char,String for text handling and byte for binary handling.What problem come when i use the opposite.For Example considering my code.

Comment: @JalajChawla: Sure - try running your code on a machine that has default encoding which isn't ASCII-compatible, for example. (More generally, look at the methods provided by the `Character` class and use those...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing each space twice :

First time here :

```
for(i=0;i<b.length;i++)
{ 
 System.out.print(" ");
 System.out.print(b[i]); // first time
}
```

Second time here :

```
           if(b[i]==' ')             
           {
             System.out.print(b[i]); // second time
           }
```

I'm assuming the latter should be removed.

For example, for the "ab cd" input, the first loop prints : `97 98 32 99 100`.
Then the condition of `if(b[i]==' ')` prints another `32`.

Answer (score 0):

@Jalaj Chawala-- use below code; i have made some changes in your existing code--

```
    class Change {
    static void change(String p) {
        if (p == null) {
          System.out.print("Null String");
        }
        int f = p.length();
        if (f == 0) {
          System.out.print(" Empty String");
        } else {
      int u = 0;
      int i = 0;
      byte d = 32;
      char c[] = p.toCharArray();
      byte b[] = p.getBytes();

      for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (b[i] >= 65 && b[i] <= 90) {
          b[i] = (byte)(b[i] + d);
        } else {
          if (b[i] >= 97 && b[i] <= 122) {
            b[i] = (byte)(b[i] - d);
          } else {
            if (b[i] == ' ') {
              // System.out.print(b[i]);
            } else {
              System.out.print("Not a valid character");
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      String s2 = new String(b);
      System.out.print(s2);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String s[]) {
    String s2 = new String("ab c");
    change(s2);
  }
```

Comment: Which changes did you make and why do they solve the OP's problem.

Comment: the very first for loop and one if block if(b[i]==' ') is having problem. i removed and edited them.